# How to get complete demo simple cart?

Tags: jquery, shopping-cart

I have seen a demo of simple shopping cart for an e-commerce site at :
http://demo.simplecartjs.com/

However, in the download it is just a basic cart. I want it to look like what is shown in the demo? But cant seem to find the correct css and pages etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you'll need this [css page](http://demo.simplecartjs.com/stylesheets/demoFullWindow.css)

Plus this HTML :

```
    <div id="demoContainer">

        <!--Create a div with the class simpleCart_shelfItem-->

        <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">

            <!--Notice the class names of each tag begin with item_ -->

            <img src="images/the-incredibles.png" alt="The Incredibles Purchase at Amazon http://amzn.com/B00005JN4W" title="Buy at www.amzn.com/B00005JN4W" class="item_image"/>

            <h5 class="item_name">Sample DVD</h5>

            <p class="item_Description">

                To create a shelf item, you create a div with a class of “simpleCart_shelfItem”.

            </p>

            <span class="item_price">$14.99</span>

            <a href="javascript:;" class="item_add">Add to Cart</a>

            <span class="item_thumb">images/the-incredibles_tn.png</span>

        </div>  



        <!--Create a div with the class simpleCart_shelfItem-->

        <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">

            <!--Notice the class names of each tag begin with item_ -->

            <img src="images/wolverine-3.png" alt="Wolverine Purchase at Amazon http://amzn.com/B002CMLIJ6" title="Buy at http://amzn.com/B002CMLIJ6" class="item_image"/>

            <h5 class="item_name">Sample DVD 2</h5>

            <p class="item_Description">

                Any field you want for your item can be set by creating a tag with a class of “item_[field-name]”

            </p>

            <span class="item_price">$22.99</span>

            <a href="javascript:;" class="item_add">Add to Cart</a>



            <span class="item_thumb">images/wolverine-3_tn.png</span>

        </div>



        <!--Create a div with the class simpleCart_shelfItem-->

        <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">

            <!--Notice the class names of each tag begin with item_ -->

            <img src="images/ghostbusters.png" alt="Ghostbusters Game Purchase at Amazon http://amzn.com/B001ELJDXE" title="Buy at http://amzn.com/B001ELJDXE" class="item_image"/>

            <h5 class="item_name">Sample Game</h5>

            <p class="item_Description">

                To create the add to cart button create a tag with the class “item_quantity”.

            </p>

            <span class="item_price">$59.99</span>

            <a href="javascript:;" class="item_add">Add to Cart</a>



            <span class="item_thumb">images/ghostbusters_tn.png</span>

        </div>

            <!--Create a div with the class simpleCart_shelfItem-->

            <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">

                <!--Notice the class names of each tag begin with item_ -->

                <img src="images/soviet-kitsch.png" alt="Soviet Kitsch Purchase at Amazon http://amzn.com/B0002XEDXU" title="Buy at http://amzn.com/B0002XEDXU" class="item_image"/>

                <h5 class="item_name">Sample CD</h5>

                <p class="item_Description">

                    If can display info about the cart anywhere on your page.

                </p>

                <span class="item_price">$8.99</span>

                <a href="javascript:;" class="item_add">Add to Cart</a>

                <span class="item_thumb">images/soviet-kitsch_tn.png</span>

            </div>  



            <!--Create a div with the class simpleCart_shelfItem-->

            <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">

                <!--Notice the class names of each tag begin with item_ -->

                <img src="images/evil-empire.png" alt="Evil Empire Purchase at Amazon http://amzn.com/B0000029D9" title="Buy at http://amzn.com/B0000029D9" class="item_image"/>

                <h5 class="item_name">Sample CD 2</h5>

                <p class="item_Description">

                    A class of simpleCart_total, will display the cart total value.

                </p>

                <span class="item_price">$8.97</span>

                <a href="javascript:;" class="item_add">Add to Cart</a>



                <span class="item_thumb">images/evil-empire_tn.png</span>

            </div>



            <!--Create a div with the class simpleCart_shelfItem-->

            <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">

                <!--Notice the class names of each tag begin with item_ -->

                <img src="images/attack-release.png" alt="Attack and Release Purchase at Amazon http://amzn.com/B0013K6WLM" title="Buy at http://amzn.com/B0013K6WLM" class="item_image"/>

                <h5 class="item_name">Sample CD 3</h5>

                <p class="item_Description">

                    A class of simpleCart_checkout will send you off to Paypal or Google Checkout

                </p>

                <span class="item_price">$13.49</span>

                <a href="javascript:;" class="item_add">Add to Cart</a>



                <span class="item_thumb">images/attack-release_tn.png</span>

            </div>







            <div id="cartTotal">

                <strong>Total: </strong><span class="simpleCart_total"></span>

            </div>

            <!--Add a div with the class of simpleCart_items to display what is in the user's cart-->

            <div class="simpleCart_items"></div>

                <!--use a class of simpleCart_empty to empty the cart and simpleCart_checkout to checkout -->

                <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_empty">Empty Cart</a>

                <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout">Checkout</a>

        <!--End #demoContainer-->

        </div>



        <script type="text/javascript">

        var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");

        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        try {

        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-5082207-10");

        pageTracker._trackPageview();

        } catch(err) {}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That demo page appears to be using just a background image for the entire design of their page (http://simplecartjs.com/images/BGDemoContent.jpg), which is odd because much of that design could be achieved relatively painlessly with CSS.

Since presumably you aren't an expert at converting images to CSS by hand, it seems like you're on your own in creating CSS/graphics for this.  Or you could just use their background image on your site, in which case you would have to edit out the "demo" text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different demo of a customizable shopping cart using Google Checkout:

https://checkout.google.com/seller/gsc/v2_2/demo/index.html

Documentation on customizing the cart UI and behavior using CSS and JavaScript is here:

https://sites.google.com/site/checkoutshoppingcart/reference